# demande dans un forum

Tags: expressions, politesse

Je veux demander l'aide dans un forum de maths concernant un exercice dont je n'ai pas la fin de l'énoncé.
Est-ce que je peux dire :

> Bonjour,
>    malheursement j'ai pas la fin de cette exercice si quelqu'un deja vu quelque part par exemple est ce qu'il sagit d'un concours de l'ecole X je serais reconnaissant.

Comment: Par "suite", est-ce que tu entends que tu n'as que le début et qu'il te manque la fin de l'énoncé de l'exercice ? Ou bien s'agit-il d'une "suite" au sens mathématique ? N'hésite pas à nous indiquer ce que tu dirais en anglais.

Comment: Oui il me manque la fin de l énoncé

Comment: Quel est le point particulier qui te pose problème ici ? Je ferme la question tant qu'il n'y a pas un point précis sur lequel les réponses peuvent se concentrer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On peut tenter d'avoir le texte complet de cette façon :

> ... malheureusement je n'ai pas la fin de l'énoncé de cet exercice.
>  Si quelqu'un l'a déjà vu quelque part, ou s'il s'agit d'un concours de l’École X, je vous serais reconnaissant de me donner le moyen de retrouver le texte intégral.